# Entire array is echoed, but not elements of it - Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this structure in Shell Script BASH

```
i=0
while read linha_reg
do
    REG_ADDRESS=$(echo $linha_reg | cut -f1 -d ' ')
    [ $REG_ADDRESS -lt 16] && T[$i]=$REG_ADDRESS || S[$i]=$REG_ADDRESS
    i=$((i+1))
done < register.txt

while read linha_inst
do
    RS=$(echo $linha_inst | cut -f4 -d ' ')
    RS=$(echo $RS | cut -f1 -d ',')

    RS_INDEX=${RS:2:2}
    RS_LETTER=${RS:1:1}

    [ "$RS_LETTER" == "s" ] && echo ${S[$RS_INDEX]} 
done < instruction.txt
```

With this snippet I have only a blank space in the echo ${S[$RS_INDEX]} when I execute it on Terminal. However, if I write

```
echo ${S[@]}
```

It outputs the entire array, as requested by the echo. If I write

```
echo ${S[3]}
```

Doesn't work also.

I'm lost because I don't know what explains this and I want it to return only a single element, as the big snippet does but it doesn't output by unknown reasons.

Cheers

Comment: You never increment (or otherwise modify) `i`; your first loop repeatedly assigns to element `0` of either array.

Comment: I did, forgot to put in the snippet hahahaha

Comment: That's not a valid assignment statement. No spaces allowed on either side of the `=`.

Comment: I'm doing this in aa Virtual Machine, so I didn't copy-paste, had to write it down everything, putting spaces in variable assignments is my habit since forever. In the code isn't with spaces.

Comment: Also, you increment `$i` whether you assign to `T` or `S`; that will leave gaps in the array you don't assign to.

Comment: Check how many elements you have in `S` with `echo ${#S[@]}` to verify you have more than 1 element. Then you know how many to expect. You may also want to post example lines of register.txt and instruction.txt. Using `echo | cut ...` is a wonky way to do what should be done by **substring extraction**.

Comment: It returned 8 @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: OK, then to see what you have in each then `for ((i=0;i<${#S[@]};i++)); do echo "S[$i] '${S[$i]}'"; done`. I suspect you have empty elements.

Comment: All the elements were really empty. But how when I write echo ${S[@]} it returns the whole array with correct values and when I look through it like the code you gave me does the elements are empty?

Comment: oh -- your indexes are not 0-7! You need 2 different counters for `T[x]` and `S[y]` in order to keep you indexes straight. use `i` for `S` and say `j` for `T`.

Comment: To keep the indexes straight, so something like `i=0; j=0; .. [ $REG_ADDRESS -lt 16] && { T[$i]=$REG_ADDRESS; ((i++)); } || { S[$j]=$REG_ADDRESS; ((j++)); }` --or-- `declare -a T; declare -a S` and then use `T+=$REG_ADDRESS` and `S+=$REG_ADDRESS`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `T+=($REG_ADDRESS)`, otherwise you simply perform string concatenation on `${T[0]}`.

Comment: @chepner good catch. Stepping on several alligators and putting out fires at the moment :)

Comment: Oh, such a primary mistake! It was really all about the indexes, thank you fellas.

Answer (score 1):

To add to an array, use `var+=(value)` like [@chepner suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534744/entire-array-is-echoed-but-not-elements-of-it-shell-script#comment39868818_25534744). Using `var[$i]=value` results in sparse arrays, where some indexes are undefined.

Also:

- [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)!
- In Bash you can use [here strings](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument#Here_Strings) like `some_command <<< "$variable"` to avoid `echo`.
- When you do `a && b || c`, `c` is run if **either** `a` or `b` fails. To avoid this, use the standard

  ```
  if a
  then
      b
  else
      c
  fi
  ```
- Use a single `=` with `[` (see `help test`).